# Advantages of closing file handle in perl

Tags: perl, file, file-handling

Advantage of closing file handle in Perl is that "$." gets

1. reset

   cleans up buffer

   gives command status

   none

Please tell me the correct answer with explanation (if possible)

Comment: You'll learn more if you do your homework yourself

Comment: For questions like these we should wait a few hours for the test/exam to be over, and THEN post the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Read this [close FILEHANDLE perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html) .

Answer (score 2):

You can also look into [perlvar for $.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.)

Answer (score 1):

There was an identical question posted to PerlMonks.  You might look there at some of the excellent answers that question received:  [Why do we need to close filehandles?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=902128)